# Capture a text from webpage using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, text-capture

I am trying to capture a piece of text from a website which keeps changing. 
It looks like :

> Order ID : XXIO-123344-3456

The prefix is constant but the numbers will always change. I want to capture this number and store it. I have tried `storeTextPresent` with regex pattern `regexp:Email.*@.*com`. It does return me a **True** but it does not return me the value. Of course `storeTextPresent` is supposed to only return **True** or **False**. So now how can I capture the exact value?

Here's a screen shot of the part of the webpage. Can't show the whole page, so sorry.

[image]

So any ideas guys?

I export these test after recording into python remote control. So python specific code is more welcome.

Comment: Can you show the code of what you actually tried and did not work?

Comment: I have no code.....Consider you visit a web page . You launch selenium IDE . Start recording . You right click on the page text you want and select "storeTextPresent" . Thats what i was trying to do . Ok just try to capture the text "viewed
8 times" on this very page . You can see it on the right hand top corner . You want to capture "8 times" . So how do you do it?

Answer (score 1):

`assertText` command with the regular expression `regexp:^XXIO-.+` would resolve the issue. Try this in conjunction with the element id you need to verify.

Comment: This won't give the desired result as it will return a boolean, not the actual text that arindam is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a look in the manual. I found the [storeText](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html#storetext)  command under [Store Commands and Selenium Variables](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html#store-commands-and-selenium-variables). My guess is that if you use storeText instead of storeTextPresent.

Also, instead of trying to find the text using a regex pattern, you could try using an [xpath](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html#locating-by-xpath), [DOM](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html#locating-by-dom), or [CSS](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html#locating-by-css) locator.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the idea but i could'nt find a locater for the text.
This is the code i captured using firebug .

```
<div class="chkOutBox">
<h2 id="tnq" class="marb10">Order Details</h2>
<div class="ordRevAddressArea">
<div class="ordRevDelSlotArea">
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="bFont">Order ID:&nbsp; BBO-72262-171012</div>
<div class="scartPgHdr">
<h3 class="catHdr">Fruits &amp; Vegetables</h3>
```

Here we are capturing the id number (Line 6)......May be someone can tell me how to figure  out a possible locater for this from the above code
....By the way I solved my problem by capturing the URL of the page which had the order ID.I used a regex to seperate out the order id and thats it.......Its only a temporary solution.......

Comment: You could even use a CSS locator. It is difficult to say what's best, because the html markup doen't convey much semantic meaning. The css classes look like they are based on visual style rather than semantic meaning. You could try `#tnq .bFont`. Better would be to add use semantic class names. Also, may I suggest that instead of adding extra information as an answer, you should edit your original question and add this information there.

Answer (score 0):

Python Code.

```
def get_order_id(driver):
    """ Gets the order id, given an Order Details page. """
    try:
        bFonts = driver.find_element_by_class_name("bFont")
        for element in bFonts:
            if "Order ID" in element.text:
                return element.text.split()[-1]
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return None
```

This assumes that the class name, `bFont` never changes.  If it does, you can rewrite it to search over the `div` tag.  It also assumes that "Order ID" will be found.